# Making an ERC20 token that the issuer has all controls over the tokens

Tags: erc-20

While I am making a toy project that has some web3 feature, I am trying to make ERC20 token that the issuer can control the tokens wherever they are. For example, the issuer can send the tokens from user A to user B without getting allowance. Since it also has all ERC20 features, I am considering to add a function "trasnferFromOwner" to the normal ERC20 contract such that

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function transferFromIssuer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        
    }
}
```

But I have no idea where to start and how I would make this function as I wish. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a recommendation you can implement the `transferFromOwner` function like that

```
function transferFromOwner(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    // First, check that the contract owner has sufficient allowance for the sender
    require(allowance(owner, sender) >= amount, "Insufficient allowance for sender");

    // Then, transfer the tokens on behalf of the sender
    _transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
}
```

Comment: it's important to ensure that the contract owner is trusted and that proper access controls are in place to prevent misuse.